# Apache Error, php extension missing - xml

Tags: php, apache2, cacti

I have installed cacti to monitor my system. Installation was easy, and everything went right.

But when I tried to access `127.0.0.1/cacti` I get this error

[image]

It is my first time on apache, Please help to get rid of this error.

This is the conf file,

```
Alias /cacti /usr/share/cacti/site

<Directory /usr/share/cacti/site>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    AllowOverride None
    <IfVersion >= 2.3>
            Require all granted
    </IfVersion>
    <IfVersion < 2.3>
            Order Allow,Deny
            Allow from all
    </IfVersion>

    AddType application/x-httpd-php .php

    <IfModule mod_php.c>
            php_flag magic_quotes_gpc Off
            php_flag short_open_tag On
            php_flag register_globals Off
            php_flag register_argc_argv On
            php_flag track_vars On
            # this setting is necessary for some locales
            php_value mbstring.func_overload 0
            php_value include_path .
    </IfModule>

    DirectoryIndex index.php
</Directory>
```

This file was automatically created during the installation process.
I installed it from here, https://www.server-world.info/en/note?os=Ubuntu_16.04&p=cacti

Comment: please add a comment before down voting, how can I improve it ?

Comment: This error is nothing to do with Apache. Your PHP instance has been compiled without the xml extension for some reason. How did you install php?

Comment: @JoeNiland you have made the right answer, I suggest you add it to the answer section directly instead of comment.

Answer (score 1):

Package php-xml is not installed on your system. 
Install it using package manager (apt, yum etc).